# creating macro in excel

Tags: vba, excel

Please help me on creating a macro which search multiple sheets in a workbook for a particular column and display the count of values in that column and display in a new sheet with sheet name and the count.

Am having 3 sheets with the name A, B & C. I have tried the below code, but it is not calculating based on the column header name.

I have columns like

Company     Company     Company
ABC         ABC         ABC 
            DEF
GHI
JKL

and the result should looks like

Sheet name  Count
A             1
B             3
C             2

Sub Click()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet, LstRw As Long, x, s As String
    Dim rng1 As Range

```
Set ws = Sheets.Add
ws.Name = "Report"
s = "A"
For Each sh In Sheets
    If sh.Name <> ws.Name Then
        With sh

              x = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("A:A"))
            With ws
                LstRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                .Cells(LstRw, 1) = sh.Name
                .Cells(LstRw, 2) = x

            End With
        End With
    End If
Next sh
```

End Sub

Thanks

Comment: Please be aware that this website does is not a code writing service, (sometimes you may be lucky and someone will help). Please look at creating a good question. provide examples of what you have tried and where the issues are along with sample data and expected outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Macros are recorded with the Macro Recorder, where Excel generates VBA code based on your actions, which you can then modify as required.

See:

- MSDN : [**Recording a Macro to Generate Code**](//msdn.microsoft.com/vba/word-vba/articles/recording-a-macro-to-generate-code), *and,*
- MSDN : [**Revising Recorded Visual Basic Macros**](//msdn.microsoft.com/vba/word-vba/articles/revising-recorded-visual-basic-macros).

---

It's best to be *"very familiar"* with Excel before trying to automate tasks with VBA.

These is a VBA tutorials are recommended as quite good/thorough/accurate:

- [**Excel VBA For Beginners**](//www.homeandlearn.org/)
- [**Ultimate VBA Tutorial**](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-tutorial-1/)

The most important documentation for VBA is from the 'official' source:

- [**Microsoft's VBA Documentation**](//msdn.microsoft.com/vba/vba-language-reference).

Comment: I did not vote, however [answer well-asked questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) might be the cause. Again - it is just an assumption.

Comment: I up-voted the answer and down-voted the question and also flagged it to  be closed as too broad. I do not think this question deserves an answer but if one answers this might be the best way to do it. Question is: Is there anything here to link to in the comment in such cases. I sometimes link to this [site](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-tutorial-1/).

Comment: @Storax - agreed. This is one of my "standard" comments on questions - then I realized this time it actually works as an answer.  ...also thank - that tutorial is indeed another good VBA tutorial to recommend, whose URL I lost a while back.

Comment: @scopchanov - I also vtc but I believe it's helpful if a user get a clue on how to proceed next time, be it tips on [ask] or even a vague answer like mine - thus helping prevent unclear questions in the future.

Comment: @ashleedawg, I understand you, however it was just a guess, what might have been the cause.